# Meteor build android taking more than 30 mins to build

Tags: meteor

I am using `meteor 1.6`, `meteor` command works perfect and run app locally within few seconds, but when I try to build meteor app for android, it takes more than 30 minutes. I found [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7493) issue thread but didn't found any solution.

I am running on:

**Device:** Mac Book Pro

**OS:** Mac OS Sierra

**Processor:** Intel Core i5 2.5GHz

**Memory:** 8GB 1333 MHz DDR3

Any solutions?

Comment: Things to look for: low on memory, low on disk space. Is it trying to run the emulator, or deploy to a real device (preferred)?

Comment: @Mikkel I updated question with system configuration.

Comment: Have you tried running with profiling enabled, to help spot where the bulk of the time is being used up. `METEOR_PROFILE=1`